# MongoDB: group using id=null

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a collection of documents of this type:

`enter code here
{ "_id": "10280", 
"city": "NEW YORK", 
"state": "NY", 
"pop": 5574,
"loc": [
-74.016323,
40.710537 ]
}`
and I have to make this mongoDB query:

Return the city with the highest number of ZIP codes

My solution is based on this:
1. make sum of zip codes for every city (grouping by city. Remember that zipcode is _id)
2. group by null to make $max (using one document)
3. project city and nr of zip codes for the city that has the max number.

AND this is my query:

`db.zipcodes.aggregate([
    {"$group": {_id:"$city", numberZipCodes: {$sum:1}}},
    {"$group": {_id: null, maxNumber: {$max: "$numberZipCodes"}}},
    {"$project":{ "city": "$_id.city", "maxNumber":1, "_id":0, "city":1}}])`
but obviously I don't have _id.city value.
How can I memorize it??

Comment: You already have the number of zip codes in this stage `{"$group": {_id:"$city", numberZipCodes: {$sum:1}}}`. So, sorting by `numberZipCodes` in descending order gets the city with highest number of zip codes as the first record. Then limit the output by `1`.

Comment: Thanks. What if I’d like to correct my query??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    db.zipcodes.aggregate([{
            $group: {
                _id: "$city",
                totalZipCodes: {
                    $sum: 1
                }
            }
        }, {
            $sort: {
                totalZipCodes: -1
            }
        },
        {
            $limit: 1
        }
    ])
```

The above aggregation pipeline has 2 stages:

1. Group total zip codes by city
2. Sort all records from stage to with number of zip codes, returning the city with maximum zipcode